# f.write, how can i fix the header at the top of the page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a python code that gives me several output values and I have created a file where a new row of data can be added every run in the same txt file. the problem is the header is written every run, and I just want to fix the header at the top of the file.

Here is what I have :

```
with open('Trial.txt', 'a') as fd:
    fd.write('{a:^8}  {b:^8}    {c:^8}      {d:^8}  {e:^8}'.format(a='DIA', b='Dia', c='Len',d='PRO',e='time'))
    fd.write("\r")
    fd.write(f'    {magnitude}          {diameter}        {Length}      {Pro_code}     {Time}')
    fd.write("\r\n")
```

the output comes in this way:

```
    DIA            Dia           Len           PRO           time
    8.0            7000          500      0.0052297            141
    DIA            Dia           Len           PRO           time
    7.0            6000          400      0.003237            161
```

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
    DIA            Dia           Len           PRO           time
    8.0            7000          500      0.0052297           141
    7.0            6000          400      0.003237            161
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you open the file in append mode you should write the header only if the file is newly created. For that you can use the `tell` method of the file object and check if it's at position 0 to tell if it's a new file, and only write the header if it is:

```
with open('Trial.txt', 'a') as fd:
    if fd.tell() == 0:
        fd.write('{a:^8}  {b:^8}    {c:^8}      {d:^8}  {e:^8}\r\n'.format(a='DIA', b='Dia', c='Len',d='PRO',e='time'))
    fd.write(f'    {magnitude}          {diameter}        {Length}      {Pro_code}     {Time}\r\n')
```

Comment: Done! Thank you!